# How to send mail, if Mail ID contails single quotes in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm sending email from Perl script. But I'm facing issue for apostrophe email id while sending email from Perl script. For example, if email id contains single quotes, Mail is not delivering using Email:: MIME Module also it doesn't throw any error. How do I send mail for apostrophe email id?

Can anyone help in this case? Thanks in Advance

```
use utf8;
use Path::Class qw/file/;
use Encode;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw/try_to_sendmail/; 
use Email::MIME;
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
use Email::Address::XS;
use Data::Dumper;


open(fh,"<test.html");
$str = join("",<fh>);

@to_address = ("sample\'test@test.com");

my %mail = ('username'=>'user','password'=>'pwd','subject'=>'Sample','body'=>$str,'host'=>hostname,'port'=>'25','display_name' => 'Test Delivery');

$mail{'files'} = \@ar_ref;
$mail{'to'} = \@to_address;
&email(\%mail);

sub email(){
my $mailinfo = shift;
my $username = $mailinfo->{'username'};
my $password = $mailinfo->{'password'};

my $from  = $mailinfo->{'username'};
my $display_name = $mailinfo->{'display_name'};
#print "from : $from\n";
my @to       = @{$mailinfo->{'to'}};
my $subject  = $mailinfo->{'subject'};
my $body     = $mailinfo->{'body'};
my $host = $mailinfo->{'host'};
my $port = $mailinfo->{'port'};
my @attachmentfiles = @{$mailinfo->{'files'}};
my @body1;
my $to = join(',',@to);
$to =~ s/(^,|,$)//g;
foreach (@attachmentfiles){
    my $file1     = file($_);
    push (@body1, Email::MIME->create(
            attributes => {
            filename     => $file1->basename,
            encoding     => 'utf-8',
            disposition  => "attachment",
            },
            body => scalar $file1->slurp,
        )
    )
}

unshift (@body1, Email::MIME->create(
    attributes => {
    content_type => 'text/html',
    charset      => 'utf-8',
    encoding     => '7bit',
    },
    body_str => $body,
    )
);
    my $email = Email::MIME->create(
    header => [
    From    => Email::Address::XS->new($display_name,$from),
    To      => $to,
    Subject => Encode::encode('utf-8', $subject),
    ],
    parts => [ @body1 ],
);
$_->encoding_set( 'base64' ) for $email->parts;
try_to_sendmail(
    $email,
    {
        transport => Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new(
            host     => $host,
            port     => $port,
            username => $username,
            password => $password,
        )
    }
) or do {
    print "Error occured while mail send\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Your code constructing the list of recipients that includes the single quote is wrong. Are you getting any Perl syntax errors, or is the actual email sending the problem? Please specify. To get a single quote into a string, use a different way of quoting. `"foo'bar"`

Comment: sorry for previous code. i have used within "foo'bar"  also. Its not delivered

Comment: Your code is disgraceful. You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, especially before asking the whole world for help to fix it. You will also have to use `my` to declare each variable as close as possible to where it is first used. You also need to indent your cide properly to make it readable. While you may wish to sacrifice readability and the debugging facilities of Perl itself for the sake of typing fewer characters, it is very ill-mannered to ask for help with code in that state.

Comment: I don't know how this module does it, but did you try `q(a'b@c.com)`, so with `q(...)`?  That way you can use a single quote inside while you also single quote it so it doesn't immediately get interpolated (the module may still do that in its own operation)

Comment: @zdim- I have tried with q(a'b@c.com) also. But same thing is happening